# How do I select an element in jQuery by using a variable for the ID?

Tags: jquery, syntax, select

For example, the following selects a division with id="2":

```
row = $("body").find("#2");
```

How do I do something like this:

```
row_id = 5;
row = $("body").find(row_id);
```

The above syntax produces an error. I checked the jQuery documentation and answers here without success.

Comment: Wow, five answers that are exactly the same...

Answer (score 215, accepted):

```
row = $("body").find('#' + row_id);
```

More importantly doing the additional body.find has no impact on performance. The proper way to do this is simply:

```
row = $('#' + row_id);
```

Answer (score 48):

The shortest way would be:

```
$("#" + row_id)
```

Limiting the search to the body doesn't have any benefit.

Also, you should consider renaming your `id`s to something more meaningful (and HTML compliant as per Paolo's answer), especially if you have another set of data that needs to be named as well.

Comment: I like concise. I just used this with qTip2 tooltips, works great. I'm a little curious what the performance penalty is for generating a lot of these "just in time" such as in response to user input.

Answer (score 28):

Doing `$('body').find();` is not necessary when looking up by ID; there is no performance gain.

Please also note that having an ID that starts with a number is [not valid HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
row_id = 5;
row = $("body").find('#'+row_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code

1. To find an element by ID you must prefix it with a "#"
2. You are attempting to pass a Number to the find function when a String is required (passing "#" + 5 would fix this as it would convert the 5 to a "5" first)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about jQuery, but try this:

```
row_id = "#5";
row = $("body").find(row_id);
```

Edit: Of course, if the variable is a number, you have to add `"#"` to the front:

```
row_id = 5
row = $("body").find("#"+row_id);
```