# using integer received on js function as param to fetch div id with same id as passed integer as param

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving some integer on js function as parameter and I want to use that value which also represents div id to append result inside div.

```
function DisplaySomeData(someData, code) {
        $.ajax({
            url: formatUrl('...'),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ data: someData}),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#+code").html(result);// how to use code to recognize div id?
            },
            error: ...
        });
```

Comment: You mean `$('#' + code).html(result);`?

Comment: `$("#"+code).html(result);` instead of `$("#+code").html(result);`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I select an element in jQuery by using a variable for the ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743994/how-do-i-select-an-element-in-jquery-by-using-a-variable-for-the-id)

Comment: @Jack: Same answer, different question (Problem in the question). Ergo, not a duplicate, imo.

Comment: @Cerbrus "select .. by using variable for id" vs "using integer .. as param to fetch div id"; that comes pretty close; that said, this question is more about a typo than anything else.

Comment: @Jack: Yea, the typo is the reason I marked it as offtopic-typo intead of dupe

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah, I thought I could switch my cv into another type but unfortunately I can't do anything after retracting the first =(

Answer (score 3):

You aren't concatenating the selector string correctly. Try this:

```
$('#' + code).html(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Syntax error in your code. If you want to select div whose id attribute 'code' which you are passing in DisplaySomeData function. below is modified syntax.

```
function DisplaySomeData(someData, code) {
    $.ajax({
        url: formatUrl('...'),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: someData}),
        success: function (result) {
            $("#"+code).html(result);// or use $("div[id='"+code+"']").html(result);
        },//Both the syntax should work
        error: ...
    });
```

Note : If you found this useful. Please mark it as answered.